# Fonts not being displayed correctly in Linux Mint 17.2 32bit

Tags: fonts

I have been using Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela for a while now, but often it is the case that fonts are not rendered correctly in the file explorer and in the web browser window. I mean something similar to this-

[[image]][1

and

[image]

The problem was with the beta version of 17.2, and even after installing a fully stable release, the problem still exists..The problem seems to vanish in 17.1 or any other OS... 
How can I resolve this ?